# Postman Test script - Set Env variable with response header query param

Tags: variables, postman

I am trying to set an env variable with a query param received in the response.

i am sending a POST request and in the response I am getting a resource id i need to use in the next request (therefore need to add it as an env variable).

the response Header:
location →
https://mmmmmmmm.nnnnnnnn.xxxxxx/oauth-signin?client_id=bbbnnnmmmm-bbnn-46ba-a287-nnhhyyy&redirect_uri=https://mmm.nnnn.nnnn/galaxy-backend/redirect/oauth/token&response_type=code&state=kYIL97&protocol=berlin-v13&consent_id=5d1372ebfb0b3a09b2ea4ddb&scope=accounts.accountDetails.read+accounts.transactions.read+accounts.balances.read

i am trying to retrieve the value form the query param 'consent_id' and set it in env variable.

my env variable is named 'ConsentId'.

i tried:
pm.environment.set('ConsentId', JSON.stringify(pm.response.header.getQueryString("consent_id")));
No luck.

Would appreciate help with how to write it so the script will get the field from the a url param in the header and place it in the env variable.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to write it so the script will get the field from the a url param in the header and place it in the env variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get `ConsentId` parameter value in `Location` response header and set it as environment variable in Postman:

```
var key = 'consent_id';
var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + key + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)');
var redirectURL = postman.getResponseHeader('Location');
var matchResult = regex.exec(redirectURL);
var consentId = decodeURIComponent(matchResult[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));

pm.environment.set('ConsentId', consentId);
```

BTW, to make above code work well, "Automatically follow redirects" option should be turned off:

[image]

Note: I failed to extract `Location` header from `pm.response.headers`, that's why `postman.getResponseHeader()` is used in above code.